# PL/SQL cursor to calculate number of projects

Tags: plsql, cursor

I am newbie at pl/sql

I have to complete procedure that computes average of select employee id that parsed through procedure paramet and calculate number of projects that that employee have taken

here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
empid number(5),
empname varchar(20),
address varchar(20),
no_of_dependents number(5),
deptno number(5),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(empid),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(deptno) REFERENCES department(deptno));

CREATE TABLE project(
projectno number(5),
location varchar(20),
incharge number(5),
rate_per_hour number(5),
CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(projectno),
CONSTRAINT PROJECT_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(incharge) REFERENCES employee(empid));

CREATE TABLE assignment(
empid number(5),
projectid number(5),
hours number(5),
CONSTRAINT ASSIGNMENT_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(empid) REFERENCES employee(empid),
CONSTRAINT ASSIGNEMNT_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(projectid) REFERENCES project(projectno));
```

and here is basically pl/sql procedure

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace procedure disp(idd number) is 

  cursor c1 is select avg(ass.hours) from assignment ass join employee e on
  e.empid=ass.empid
  where ass.empid=idd;

  cursor c2 is select empname from employee where empid=idd;
  v_name varchar(20);

  cursor c3 is select count(p.projectno)
  from employee e join project p on
  e.empid=p.incharge
  where p.incharge=idd;
  v_count_nr number;




begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 into v_avg_nr;
  close c1;
  open c2;
  fetch c2 into v_name;
  close c2;
  open c3;
  fetch c3 into v_count_nr;
  close c3;

  dbms_output.put_line('Employee: '||idd);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Name: '||v_name);
  dbms_output.put_line('Number of projects: '||v_count_nr);
  dbms_output.put_line('Average Working Hours: '||v_avg_nr);



  end disp;
  /

  execute disp(101);
```

I am expecting problems where the **c3** has to count the number of projects employee took

It is counting incorrectly
here is the output what I am getting:

```
Employee: 101
Employee Name: Marlen
Number of projects: 20
Average Working Hours: 107.4
```

Thanks for help! how can I check if the average working hours is less than 10 then employee’s salary remain the same, otherwise check if number of project is less than 4 then 5% of salary, else 10% of salary is added to the salary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `group by` clause in your `c3` cursor. Also, `c1` is the average working hours for all employees: is this what you're expecting?

Why an sproc? You can achieve what you are doing in a regular query using standard aggregation functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've modified the c3 cursor c3 is select count(p.projectno)
  from employee e join project p on
  e.empid=p.incharge
  where p.incharge=idd;
  v_count_nr number;